# Wireless problem with Broadcom BCM4313

Tags: wireless, broadcom, b43

I have wireless connection problem can't connect my wireless

lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4

> 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)

iwconfig

> eth0      no wireless extensions.
>
> lo        no wireless extensions.
>
> wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any
>             Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated
>             Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
>             Power Management:off

rfkill list all

> 0: hci0: Bluetooth
>   Soft blocked: no
>   Hard blocked: no
>   1: phy0: Wireless LAN
>     Soft blocked: no
>     Hard blocked: no
>   2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
>     Soft blocked: no
>     Hard blocked: no

lsmod

> Module                  Size  Used by
>   bnep                   19624  2
>   rfcomm                 69160  8
>   ip6t_REJECT            12939  1
>   xt_hl                  12521  6
>   ip6t_rt                13537  3
>   nf_conntrack_ipv6      18894  8
>   nf_defrag_ipv6         34768  1 nf_conntrack_ipv6
>   ipt_REJECT             12541  1
>   xt_LOG                 17717  10
>   xt_limit               12711  13
>   xt_tcpudp              12884  18
>   xt_addrtype            12635  4
>   nf_conntrack_ipv4      15012  8
>   nf_defrag_ipv4         12758  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
>   xt_conntrack           12760  16
>   ip6table_filter        12815  1
>   ip6_tables             27025  1 ip6table_filter
>   nf_conntrack_netbios_ns    12665  0
>   nf_conntrack_broadcast    12589  1 nf_conntrack_netbios_ns
>   nf_nat_ftp             12770  0
>   nf_nat                 21798  1 nf_nat_ftp
>   nf_conntrack_ftp       18638  1 nf_nat_ftp
>   nf_conntrack           96976  8   >nf_nat_ftp,nf_conntrack_netbios_ns,nf_nat,xt_conntrack,nf_conntrack_broadcast,nf_conntrack_ftp,nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_conntrack_ipv6
>   iptable_filter         12810  1
>   ip_tables              27239  1 iptable_filter
>   vx_tables               34059  13   >ip6table_filter,xt_hl,ip_tables,xt_tcpudp,xt_limit,xt_conntrack,xt_LOG,iptable_filter,ip>6t_rt,ipt_REJECT,ip6_tables,xt_addrtype,ip6t_REJECT
>   uvcvideo               80885  0
>   videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
>   videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
>   snd_hda_codec_hdmi     46207  1
>   videobuf2_core         40664  1 uvcvideo
>   videodev              134688  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
>   snd_hda_codec_conexant    57441  1
>   snd_hda_intel          52355  8
>   snd_hda_codec         192906  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_intel 
>   snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
>   snd_pcm               102099  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
>   snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
>   snd_seq_midi           13324  0
>   dm_multipath           22873  0
>   snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
>   scsi_dh                14882  1 dm_multipath
>   lib80211_crypt_tkip    17619  0
>   snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi
>   intel_powerclamp       14705  0
>   coretemp               13435  0
>   kvm_intel             143060  0
>   kvm                   451511  1 kvm_intel
>   joydev                 17381  0
>   serio_raw              13462  0
>   snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
>   intel_ips              18664  0
>   wl                   4207846  0
>   snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
>   btusb                  32412  0
>   bluetooth             395423  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
>   snd_timer              29482  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
>   snd                    69238  26   >snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
>   lib80211               14381  2 wl,lib80211_crypt_tkip
>   toshiba_bluetooth      12852  0
>   cfg80211              484040  1 wl                                              >lpc_ich                21080  0
>   fglrx                8085343  190
>   soundcore              12680  1 snd
>   toshiba_acpi           22901  0
>   sparse_keymap          13948  1 toshiba_acpi
>   wmi                    19177  1 toshiba_acpi
>   amd_iommu_v2           19054  1 fglrx
>   video                  19476  0
>   mei_me                 18627  0
>   mei                    82276  1 mei_me
>   mac_hid                13205  0
>   parport_pc             32701  0
>   ppdev                  17671  0
>   lp                     17759  0
>   parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
>   hid_generic            12548  0
>   usbhid                 52570  0
>   hid                   106148  2 hid_generic,usbhid
>   psmouse               102222  0
>   ahci                   25819  3
>   libahci                32168  1 ahci
>   atl1c                  46086  0
>   dm_mirror              22135  0
>   dm_region_hash         20862  1 dm_mirror
>   dm_log                 18411  2 dm_region_hash,dm_mirror

Can someone give any ideas on how I can fix my wireless

Comment: What is the output of `uname -r`?

Comment: What is your version of ubuntu?12.04 or later?

Comment: 3.13.0-29-generic

My ubuntu version is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Search Unity for additional drivers.

There should be an option **Broadcom STA Wireless driver**

Select it, then maybe you need to reboot your PC.

More information:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

Comment: I read this page and I don't solve my problem

Comment: What about the addition drivers part?